# How to use swagger code-generator

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

I am working on creating the rest client and I will be calling an API which gives this big json output .I want to know how to create the Pojo classes automatically by inputting this json to swagger code gen and let it create my pojo classes for me which will save manual time . Here is what I have tried

To generate a PHP client for http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json, please run the following

```
git clone https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen
cd swagger-codegen
mvn clean package
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate \
   -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json \
   -l php \
   -o /var/tmp/php_api_client
```

(if you're on Windows, replace the last command with `java -jar modules\swagger-codegen-cli\target\swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l php -o c:\temp\php_api_client`)

I could not get pass the mvn clean package and it is giving the error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project swagger-codegen: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
>   [ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/swagger/models/properties/Property

Anyone have successfully used this swagger ? or even if you can suggest any other framework which can do this functionality would be of great help . Thanks in advance ..,

I seen the following link 
[Update code generated by Swagger code-gen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886056/update-code-generated-by-swagger-code-gen) 
 and able to run the application .. Can anyone explain if I can use this to get the pojo object created for the json input?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not swagger itself. Your problem comes from maven and it says that it can't find a certain class. I downloaded the repo and it compiles on my machine with mvn validate package. Make sure you have .m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-models... in your standard maven cache directory. Thats the dependency, which has the Property class.
Actually maven should download it right before compiling. Check the maven output for connection errors or unreachable downloads etc.

Comment: Can you share your settings.xml for maven ? You can just delete any credentials in settings.xml and can share ?

Comment: I don't have a any maven settings.xml on my current pc.I downloaded codegen project from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen and execute mvn install. It will compile all "subprojects" from the module folder and install them into your local maven cache (usually C:\Users\MyAccount\.m2\...). after that you can use for example: 
java -jar C:\Users\MyAccount\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-codegen-cli\2.3.1\swagger-codegen-
cli-2.3.1.jar generate -i .\swagger.yaml -l java -o .\codegen\ -c .\swagger-config.json
in your cmd or power shell